# tomcat not accessible /manager is accessible

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, deployment, tomcat7

I'm running a tomcat server on OS X.
Tomcat is started with the command:

```
sh catalina.sh start
```

When I go to localhost:8080 nothing shows up (just a blank page) but when I go to localhost:8080/manager I can login and I can see the manager page.

Also when I try to deploy my app through maven I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project docFlow-core: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fcore&war= -> [Help 1]
```

I'm running a Tomcat 7 instance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, the manager app is not bundled with your default tomcat installation anymore, probably for security reasons. You can however download and install it yourself as explained on the tomcat website.